# Why does the "w" command display bash's arguments as "ÿ¿"?

Tags: macos, terminal, big-sur, unicode

The venerable [`w`](https://ss64.com/osx/w.html) utility reports who's logged on, what processes they're running, etc.
Why does it print two non-ascii characters, apparently as the (nonexistent) args for bash?

In iTerm2 they render as white question marks on a black background.
Piped to a file and viewed with vi, I see:

```
15:41  up 5 days,  1:46, 11 users, load averages: 1.67 1.69 1.47
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
me       console  -                Fri13   5days -
me       s000     -                Fri14   28:15 -bash         ÿ¿    /bin/bash
me       s001     -                Fri15    3:21 -bash         ÿ¿    /bin/bash
```

When ssh'd into the mac from a Windows PuTTY 0.74 shell, they render as ▒▒ .
The man page for `w` suggests that it might print a hyphen, but doesn't even hint at Unicode.

Comment: What happens when you issue `w` like this ?    ` LC_ALL-C w`

Comment: LC_ALL=C causes no change.